# +/- equation with a single textfield

Tags: php, html, equation

I am making a very simple storage system, and i want to make it so that the user puts a number in the box, and press the + or - button, to add or subtract.

[image: the layout of the storage system]

I don't know if it's even possible to do it, as simple as i wanted it to be :) 
but anyway, here is the code so far for index.php

```
    <?php $v_stk = "v_stk" ?>
    <form action="index_sql.php" method="POST">
    <input name="v_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $v_assoc["v_id"] ?>" />
    <input name="v_stk" type="textfield" size="8" />
    <input name="+" type="submit" value="+" style="height:23px; width:35px;" />
    <input name="-" type="submit" value="-" style="height:23px; width:35px;" />
    </form>
    <td class="width50 sidepadding">
    <?php echo $v_assoc["v_stk"]; ?></td>           
    <?php }; ?>
```

and here is for index_sql.php

```
    <?php
    require("db/db.php");

    $v_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["v_id"]);
    $v_stk = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["v_stk"]);
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT v_stk FROM vare WHERE v_id = '$v_id'");
    $assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    $v_nu = $v_stk + $assoc;

    mysql_query("UPDATE vare SET v_nu = '$v_stk' WHERE v_id = '$v_id'");
    header("location: index.php");
    ?>
```

I don't know if it is remotely close to something that would work, but with this code it gives me:
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\lager\index_sql.php on line 8

Comment: sounds much more like something you could do with client side JavaScript

Comment: yea, client side is the answer, just attach a click event to the +/- buttons, so it takes the value of the text field and +/- 1 then add new value to text field

Comment: Yuor error goes here : `$v_nu = $v_stk + $assoc;` change this to `$v_nu = $v_stk + $assoc['v_stk'];` but I agree with saturnmix and Liam. Go javascriot instead, and let a single submit take cate of updating the table.

Comment: still need a written example of the button, because i have never really gotten into JavaScript, and therefore cant write it myself, and i cant seem to find anything on the web.
when you write a number in the textfield, i need the + button to ad it to the "på lager" field.

Answer (score 0):

Because, You are performing addition with an array type variable.

```
$assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

Here, $assoc is an array variable so try like this,

```
$v_nu = $v_stk + $assoc['v_stk'];
```

Comment: beated me with seconds :-)